# Can't update or install anything on Elementary OS loki

Tags: release-loki, appcenter, repositories

**I can't install any programs from AppStore or via 'sudo apt-get install' .
I tried all: 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and 'sudo apt update' and 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt install packagekit':**

This is what I get after running 'sudo apt update': https://pastebin.com/j8GsWBwb

Comment: You have to select a working ubuntu mirror as "rs.ubuntu" seems to have errors

Answer (score -1):

Can you browse internet ?
Seems your package list pissed of...
Remove the file by `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list` then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`